# How does one insert a passive check result remotely into Opsview 6?

Tags: opsview

We are working with Opsview 6. I would like to insert a passive check result into the monitoring server remotely. The documentation is very vague about this, saying that it can be done via the API (no reference to this in the API docs), and that it is a part of the results forwarder. I don't see any open ports related to the results forwarder, so there must be something that needs to run to accept input somewhere, I'm just clueless what that might be. I'm willing to work with NSCA, NRD, or the API. Whatever works.